# CORS on react request to node.js API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

This is my node,js API,that works with no problems using postman, but when I try to make a request from a different origin like a react project the request is blocked

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
const routes  = require('./routes/routes');
const token = require('./config/config');
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', routes);

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server listening on port', port));
const url = "mongodb://localhost/titles_db";

mongoose.connect(url,{})
    .then( () => console.log('DB connected'))
    .catch( (e) => console.log('Erorr on db connection'));
```

and this is the function that is  called on my request

```
searchTitles = (req, res) => {
    const terms = req.query.terms;
    const format = req.query.format;

    titleSchema.find({title: {$regex:terms, $options: 'i'}})
        .then( data => {
            if(format == 'json')
                res.json(data);
            else{
                res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
                res.send(data);
            } 
        })
        .catch( error => res.json( {message: error}))
}
```

and here is the function that makes the request on the frontend

```
const getFieldText = e => {
    setTerm({term: e.target.value });
    const url = `http://localhost:9000/api/titles/?terms=${e.target.value}&format=json`
    
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .then(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

even including cors library on node

```
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

I get this response

```
Response { type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:9000/api/titles/?terms=aaaaaa&format=json", redirected: false, status: 403, ok: false, statusText: "Forbidden", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
```

I added an options array  but I have the same result

```
var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
  }

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

Comment: You will still need to allow the corse origin for localhost:9000: see here for how to set up the cors allowed origin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: @ColinHale OP is already using this package

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yes, but OP is only doing app.use(cors()) in the code it does not show setting up the cors allow origin. Using cors and allowing the origin are two different things.

Comment: `app.use(cors())` allows cors for all endpoints for all methods and for all origins

Comment: [cors allows all origins by default](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/f038e7722838fd83935674aa8c5bf452766741fb/lib/index.js#L41)

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski: Please consider adding a response.  Specify exactly what the OP should try (above and beyond what he's already doing).

Comment: @paulsm4 sorry but I have no idea. I just wanted to say that it's not the fault of misconfigured cors module. The only other thing that could be wrong is the URL. @a_dv85, can you show us how do you declare the enpoint? `/api/titles` etc?

Answer (score 0):

configure the cross headers like this (in your server node config):

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:8080");

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Origin');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what `cors` module do

Comment: didn't work , using "http://localhost:3000" I get the same result still blocked

Comment: res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");